# Write a Query to get desired transformed output from given table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-analysis

[image: the First table is given dbo.sales table]

[image: the desired output]

I want a query with can give output as shown in the second photo,  as the data is given in the first table(photo)

Comment: Post text not images

Answer (score 0):

This transformation of converting columns to rows is called Pivot in SQL.

```
    SELECT Region,[2010],[2011],[2012],[2013],[2015]
    FROM 
        (SELECT *
        FROM SalesTable) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
       Avg(Sales)
       FOR Year in 
      ([2010],[2011],[2012],[2013],[2015])
    ) as pvt;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with tmp as (
select f1.region, f1.Year, sum(f1.Sales) Sales 
from dbo.sales f1
group by f1.region, f1.Year
)
select distinct f1.Region, 
f2.Sales as [2010], f3.Sales as [2011], f4.Sales as [2012], f5.Sales as [2013], f6.Sales as [2014], f7.Sales as [2015] 
from tmp f1
left outer join tmp f2 on f1.Region=f2.Region and f2.year=2010
left outer join tmp f3 on f1.Region=f3.Region and f3.year=2011
left outer join tmp f4 on f1.Region=f4.Region and f4.year=2012
left outer join tmp f5 on f1.Region=f5.Region and f5.year=2013
left outer join tmp f6 on f1.Region=f6.Region and f6.year=2014
left outer join tmp f7 on f1.Region=f7.Region and f7.year=2015
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer conditional aggregation for pivoting:

```
select id,
       max(case when year = 2010 then sales end) as sales_2010,
       max(case when year = 2011 then sales end) as sales_2011,
       max(case when year = 2012 then sales end) as sales_2012,
       max(case when year = 2013 then sales end) as sales_2013,
       max(case when year = 2014 then sales end) as sales_2014,
       max(case when year = 2015 then sales end) as sales_2015
from t
group by id
order by id;
```